# Unknown file format, need to open!

Tags: images, encryption, file-format

A friend recently handed me an old disc which should contain digitized old family photographs. The problem is, the disc was created by a photographer who scanned the photos back in 2003, and has since disappeared.

I now have the disc, and upon looking at the files, I can't work out how to open them. The CD contains a series of 100 files, no file extension aside from the 2nd file which has the extension .HIG. All files are named from 01-100. They are all mostly under 10mb, aside from a few.

I've already tried unpacking them with WinRAR, assuming they were an archive. I have also tried adding a common image type extension.

Can anyone help me work out how to read these? It's a bit of a mystery.

Comment: What OS do you have available?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: Open a picture with Notepad. You should see the metadata information about which program to use to open the file.

Comment: The metadata may be difficult to interpret if you're not familiar with image formats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try installing [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows) and see if its `identify` command can tell you what they are.

Comment: Excellent, thanks guys.                                               I checked the files using notepad, as per r0ca's suggestion and from the sequence in the header (8BPS, 8BPM...) they appeared to be PSD files. ImageMagick confirmed this. I don't have photoshop but I found a free PSD viewer that works fine!

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to do it. Follow this guide on [how to open unknown file format](http://www.pcperformancetools.com/how-to-open-unknown-file-types.html).